# For which file types does IKImageBrowserView create thumbnails by default?

Tags: macos, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit

`IKImageBrowserView` does create thumbnails (show images in the browser view as opposed to an empty rectangle) for certain image formats, but also for PDFs and certain movie formats.

For which file types does `IKImageBrowserView` create thumbnails by default?
I could nowhere find any information about this in the Apple documentation.